# How to TRACE "duplicated lang item in crate std: ..."

Tags: runtime, no-std

I have an error of duplicated std, I know there is a lot of questions with the same problem, that's why I'm asking how to *search* for the problem.

I basically have an error of this form (I'm trying to keep it generic):

```
duplicate lang item in crate std: [lang item]

the lang item is first defined in crate sp_io (which [crate] depends on)
first definition in "sp_io" loaded from ...
second definition in "std" loaded from ...
```

in the case of a `the lang item is first defined in crate std (which [crate] depends on)`, the issue probably comes from `[crate]`, but on my example, I don't explicitly know which crates depends on std.

Solutions to try:

- [x] Ensure that all of the imported crates have `[default-features = false]`
- [x] Use `cargo tree` to track what could depend on `std`
- [x] Ensure all your dependencies are set to the same branch and tag
- [x] Ensure that `serde` is not causing the problem (if used)

Unfortunately, none of these solutions worked for me, that's why I'm asking for more.

For reference, my issue comes from [here](https://github.com/kabocha-network/parachain/tree/kab-release-v0.2.6)

Comment: A bit tedious but maybe you can comment some of the external pallets you have add to see with one is the one making your node fail

Comment: Hey Alex, I did comment every deps one by one, until I've found the one causing this: cumulus-pallet-session-benchmarking... I'm gonna investigate a little bit, but I think this is really weird that this pallet is causing the error..